# Integer-valued polynomial question

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, integer-valued-polynomials

Let us have an $f(x)$ Integer-valued polynomial, which gains the value $1$ in $4$ different places. Prove, that in that case, it can't gain the value $-1$ on integer places.

I tried with $f(x)-1=0$, which is true $4$ times, so the polynom's degree must be at least 4. But how do I go on? Derivating seemed a good idea, but I don't know what do after, any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by integer-valued? Why does $$f(x)=\tfrac 13(x-1)(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)+1$$ not work? It maps $f:\mathbb Z\rightarrow\mathbb Z$ since $(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)$ is always divisible by $3$ for $x\in\mathbb Z$. This has $f(1)=f(-1)=f(-2)=f(-3)=1$ and $f(0)=-1$. Perhaps you mean polynomials with integer coefficients?

Comment: Yeah, that was I meant. I will correct it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is factor $f(x)-1$, which you know to have at least four distict linear factors.  This then lets you write $f(x)$ in the form $(x-n_1)(x-n_2)(x-n_3)(x-n_4)g(x)+1$, then to show that $f(m) \ne -1$ for any integer $m$, you need to show that the product $(m-n_1)(m-n_2)(m-n_3)(m-n_4)g(m)$ cannot possibly take on the value $-2$.  Here you will have to figure our how to take advantage of the fact that the $n_i$ are distinct.

Comment: I can't really go on, can you explain a bit more? :)

Comment: Try to bound the absolute value $|(m-n_1)(m-n_2)(m-n_3)(m-n_4)|$ from below using the fact that $m$ and the $n_i$ are all distinct.  Note that $|m-n_i|\ge 1$ for every $n_i$, but how many times can equality hold?

Comment: I think equality can only hold once, since they are different, and $m$ is fixed, but how exactly that supposed to help?

Comment: It would help in that you can then prove that $|m-n_i| \ge 2$ for all of the other $i$.  However, you should be more careful in looking for solutions of $|m-n_i| = 1$.

Comment: Good question :)

Comment: I can't find the solution :(